# Esami: "No language" error during compilation

Tags: languages, esami

I'm getting this error when I try to compile a (almost empty) `tex` source using the `esami` package:

```
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.182 ... language will be used.}}{NO LANGUAGE!!!}
                                              \fi
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/We82rF29) is the complete log file and below is the **updated** `tex` file I am trying to run:

```
\documentclass[italian,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[italian,shuffle,solutions]{esami}

\def\examname{Test}
\def\numcompiti{21}
\date{2014/5/28}
\def\Data{\longdate}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{esame}

\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
\randomi=\seme
\string\large\string\textbf{Soluzione Versione n. \thevers}
\testa
\istruzionii

\begin{test}
    \begin{questions}
    \newproblem {
        \item Question
        \begin{answers}
        \bChoices[random]
            \Ans1 Answer \eAns
            \Ans0 Another answer \eAns
        \eChoices
        \end{answers}
    }
\end{questions}
\end{test}

\closevers

}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling it using `pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex` due to a warning regarding the `ifplatform` package. What is wrong here?

Comment: You should pass the `italian` option also to `esami` or have it in the global options (that is, next to `12pt` in the `\documentclass` line).

Comment: Done, but it changes nothing :( Plus, in the documentation italian is the default language, so I don't see why I should put the option...

Comment: No, no language is set by default, since in the package there is no `\ExecuteOptions` instruction. The `xyz` option doesn't exist, so you have to remove it. Moreover, it seems that you have to provide `\date{24/5/2014}` (any date, of course) or the package will hiccup. And some contents is necessary anyway.

Comment: I have updated my question with a more complete example

Comment: What should `\testa` and `\istruzionii` mean? And what's `\pagestyle{esame}` supposed to do? There's no `esame` pagestyle.

Comment: Those are commands defined by the package... I'm following the instructions in the documentation.

Comment: No, `\testa` and `\istruzionii` are not defined.

Comment: That's what the documentation says... anyway, removing them doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ok the problem is solved: apparently the italian language file wasn't present, thus the error. Again, the documentation says it should be, so I think the problem is inside the `deb` package that contains the `esami` package.

Comment: @egreg, the macro `\testa` creates a table in the upper part of the page, where the student can write his name, surname, signature, ecc. The macro `\istruzionii` prints some instructions just above the previous table, to tell the students how to behave during the exam. They are both defined in the configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macros `\testa` and `\istruzionii` are defined in the configuration file that comes with the `esami` package. In your example, you had not specified the option for your configuration file among the options of the `esami` package, so the two macros and the `\pagestyle{esame}` were not defined.
The option "italian" for the language has to be specified only as an option for the class `article`. The package was distributed with a wrong configuration under texlive and when you install it the language files are put in the wrong directory (if I'm not mistaken, the doc directory) so latex does not find them. We have already reported the problem to the texlive team and it should be solved in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, as I said in one of the comments, I found out where the problem was and solved it. I have another issue, though, as later in the compilation I get an `Undefined control sequence` of `\i -> \@nil`

Comment: Are you using the same file you have posted above?

Comment: No, here[1] is the updated one [1]: http://pastebin.com/WfbsXWbs and here[2] is the test1.tex file [2]:http://pastebin.com/b8wcXjas

Comment: Also, the configuration file is the same as the default one, just changed the name to match the option.

Comment: The main problem in your test1.tex file is that you have not specified the number of columns in which you want the answers to be placed:
    `\begin{answers}{1}`
if you want them placed the one under the other (or 2, or what you want). This parameter is mandatory.
The new structure you are using (exercises in a separate file) is the best one. 
Another thing you may want to specify is the total of points of the test (not mandatory)

Comment: I changed that, but still having the same issue... The error is located at the `}` after the `\closevers` command.

Comment: Can you please post a link to your cfg file the same way you posted the test1.tex file?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/pmsTbR5m Thanks!

Comment: Where do you define the `\code` macro? Do you load any other package?

Comment: `\code` is just another name for `\texttt`. I don't load any other package.

Comment: Here your files compile perfectly after having inserted the number of columns for the answers. The configuration file must have the name esami-mike.cfg, otherwise the package does not find it.