# Esami: questions side-by-side

Tags: esami

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180118/esami-no-language-error-during-compilation) question, my problem has now shifted to this: I managed to generate the exam pdf, but some of the questions appears next to the previous one rather than below, even if this means that i can see only the question number and first couple of words.

Something like this:

```
1. Question                 |
    a stuff                 |
    b more stuff            |
    c other stuff           |
2. Question            3. Que
    a different stuff       |
    b casual stuff          |
    c random stuff          |
```

I have set no option that involves columns in the `\usepackage` nor used the `multicols` environment.

Can someone help me?

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Yb5LR1KW) is the main `tex` file

[Here](http://pastebin.com/cNsywckH) is the `cfg` file

[Here](http://pastebin.com/umgf6wyt) are the three problems: each one should be put on a different file (problema1, problema2, problema4 in the main file)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: It is impossible to provide such MWE, since the package involves random selection from a bunch of test files, thus making the reproduction pretty much casual... I can provide more info about the files if needed.

Comment: @Cynical You should attempt to make a MWE with a deterministic set of questions - find two or three that, when selected, create the problem and post the static code as a MWE.  It will be next to impossible to answer this question as it is posed.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the file of exercises that you are using as you did yesterday?

Comment: @Cynical, I cannot reproduce the problem with your file. In the main file, I just commented the braces with eserc inside ({eserc} at the end of the `\estraies` macro). The exercises are placed one under the other as expected. I have split your exercise file in 3 different files, named problema1.tex, problema2.tex, problema4.tex. I have also tried out with 20 versions, but everything displays as expected. Did I understand correctly everything you have done?

Comment: @grames, yes, you have understood correctly. Yet I still have the problem, even after a clean rebuild. Some of the exercises are just put next to the other, going outside the page.

Comment: On the doc file of the esami package there is my email address. Can you please send me all the files you are working on, so I can check them? Sometimes I have experimented this problem and it is related to some spaces that are not placed as expected. You can try one more thing: in the es-italian.lng, check for the macro \IntelligentComma and comment it. Sometimes the problem simply disappears with this trick.

Comment: Apparently I managed to solve the issue by putting new lines before and after each `newproblem` command. Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! It was one of the things I would like to control: in your example files the \newproblem macros were separated by a space, so the problem did not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the solution for this problem is to put a space between the `\newproblem` commands in the exercise file.